# NodeJS: Data persistence layer

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node.js-typeorm

We are building the messaging application in javascript using nodejs. As part of durability of the overall solution, we need to store text messages and media content outside ejabberd. To keep the text messages we used DynamoDB, DB as Service. But when we port-in the solution with different customers, customers are asking for different DBs for which they have licenses, like mysql, postgres, sql server, oracle, DB2, mongoDB etc...

Now my question is,

1. Does ORM/ODM is a good fit here for a loosely coupled persistency layer? If so, javascript supports ORM/ODM based solution
2. If ORM/ODM is not good fit, what are the alternatives

Just a thought, I looked at TypeORM, it does provide loosely coupled persistency layer to port-in with different back-end systems..., is this a feasible framework to take it forward.
Happy to hear experts inputs.

Regards
Venkata Madhu

Answer (score 0):

`TypeORM` is a good candidate since it supports almost all the databases you mentioned (except `DB2`), I've worked with it and it's one of the best if you also want good typescript support.